# How to delay flyspell also after space?

Tags: flyspell

Flyspell has `flyspell-delay` and `flyspell-delayed-commands` which delay the spellchecking process when point is still in the word. However, `flyspell-delay` is not taken into account after typing space. Why is that and how can it be changed?

For instance, in a fresh uncustomized `emacs -Q`, `flyspell-delay` defaults to 3 seconds and `flyspell-delayed-commands` includes `self-insert-command`.

In the scratch buffer, I enable flyspell with `(flyspell-mode 1)`, and then type some random string. If I don't press `[space]`, the red underlining appears only after the specified delay. But if I press `[space]` at the end of the string, then the underline appears instantly.

`describe-key` tells me that `[space]` just calls `self-insert-command`.

What am I missing, and how can I make flyspell always respect `flyspell-delay` for `flyspell-delayed-commands`?

Comment: The space terminates a word, so `flyspel`l *wants* to check that word and flag it as a potential error immediately. The check is done in `flycheck-post-command-hook` which seems to check only a word or two or maybe a few. If you keep typing say for a minute and type 60 words without delaying more than the three seconds, when you stop, you would only be checking the last few words typed, missing everything else. At least, that's how I read the code but I am sleep-deprived, so who knows? *If* I am right, then doing what you want would render `flyspell` ineffective, so you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @NickD. I understand the logic. The reason why I'm looking into this is that flyspell makes Emacs a bit unresponsive when I write fast. I know that it's not an uncommon problem. I just tried `flyspell-lazy` and it seems to solve my problem, I'm still interested in an answer regarding the mechanism that triggers flyspell on the previous word when I hit [space], despite [space] being inserted by `self-insert-command` which is normally in `flyspell-delayed-commands`.